# Disabled Azure Function Still Pulls Messages off of Azure Storage Queue

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

I have a basic QueueTrigger Azure function.  When I disable the function in the azure portal it's still pulling messages off the storage queue (because when I look at the queue in the Azure Queue Storage Explorer the queue is empty and if i add a message it is immediately pulled off).

Here is the code:

```
[FunctionName("ProcessMessage")]
public static void Run([QueueTrigger("queue-name", Connection = "queue-connection")] Models.Message message, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {message}");
}
```

I noticed that when I stop the whole functions app it stops processing messages off the queue, but I was hoping that I could disable queue processing temporarily without stopping the whole function app.  How does one do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have V1 or V2 function app?

Comment: it is a v1 function app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the V1 function created in Visual Studio does not work in the azure portal. You should use the attribute:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function#functions-1x---c-class-libraries 
(see important section)

Comment: ohh yuck.  I guess I'll have to implement this but seems pretty terrible to have a switch that gives the impression of doing something, but in reality it's not doing anything